# Trigonometric bearing problem

Tags: trigonometry

I have two trigonometric problems that I solved, however it does not match the answer in the book:

> 1) A yacht crosses the start line of a race on a bearing of $31$ degrees. After $4.3$ km, it rounds a buoy and sails on a bearing of $346$ degrees. When it is due north of its start, how far has it sailed altogether.

I calculated the answer to be $6.353$ km. However the book's answer is $13$ m. The units are themselves different.

> 2) The bearing of $B$ and $A$ is $65$ degrees. The bearing of $C$ from $B$ is $150$ degrees, and the bearing of $A$ from $C$ is $305$ degrees. If $AC=300$m, find $BC$.

I calculated the answer to be $-1333.838$. However the answer in the book was $261$ km.  The units are themselves different as well.

> 3) The bearing of $Y$ from $X$ is $205$ degrees. The bearing of $Z$ from $Y$ is $315$ degrees, and the bearing of $X$ from $Z$ is $85$ degrees. If $XY = 4$ km, find the distance $XY$.

I calculated the answer to be $3.26$ km.

The questions are from Edexcel IGCSE Ex-181* 
Please check if my answers are correct? If not please show the steps to get the correct answer. I used the sine rule to solve these sums.

Comment: For the second question, how can a distance $BC$ ever be negative?

Comment: For problem 1, I'm guessing those bearings are 31 degrees (West?) of North and 346 degrees (14 degrees East?) of North? Using those, I get 9.154km.

Comment: used radian mode sorry, not degree

Comment: how do you delete a question?

Comment: There should be a delete button at the bottom of the question.  Otherwise, flag it for a moderator and give your comment asking to delete.

Answer (score 1):

The boat leaves at a bearing of 31 degrees and ends up north of it's start point. Therefore first corner of the triangle is 31 degrees.

At the buoy it has a bearing of 346 which is NW - ish. This angle is equal to 135 degrees.
1st part of angle is 90-31= 59degrees using construction lines and the alternate angles theorem. The second part of the angle is 346-270=76 degrees. (the bearing minus the East-West construction line) so 76+59=135 degrees.

The last angle is 180-135-31=14 degrees.

I now use Sine rule: x/sin135  =  4.3/sin 14. x = 12.57 - which rounds to 13km.

Answer (score 0):

For problem number 1, I agree with you, the pdf was totally wrong

For problem number 2, I'm sorry to say this but you are wrong and the book is almost correct because the exact value of BC is 260.80004m

For problem number 3, what is "if XY=4km, find the distance XY?"

Your problems are hard to comprehend since they are grammatically wrong.

"A yacht crosses the start line of a race on a bearing of 31 degrees."

bearing of what now? to what point? if you are telling me it's implied in the succeeding sentence, the sentence including the word "bearing itself" must contain the objective point from the reference point.

"The bearing of B and A is 65 degrees."

i think the "and" there should be "from." try it, it totally fits the problem.

for problem number 3, i didn't bother solving it because i don't really know what line was being solved.

but what the heck. i ended up solving it, although im not sure with the answers

$ ZY=5.126851056km$

$ZX=5.315704195km$

Answer (score 0):

In problem number 1, I got the answer of 9.15 km (distance between the buoy and the north of the starting point). Then to find the total distance the yacht has sailed altogether, I added 9.15 km and 4.3 km. I got the answer of 13.45 km. I guess the unit in your book is wrong because it should be in km and I think the answer was rounded off in the nearest unit/whole number that's why it became 13.

Answer (score -3):

[This is the answer for the question no2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0OW9b.jpg)

[this is the answer for the question no3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRLpr.jpg)